# Javascript Scrolling Parallax covering up other items on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this neat smooth scrolling background snippet and I tweeked it a bit.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have these three scrolling backgrounds in the beginning and then after the last one is done, my other div's on the page will show.  In my example, no matter what information you put at the bottom of the div or above it, the background hides it all.

If there's an easier way to accomplish this type of smooth scrolling, that'd be great, but I haven't found one quite like this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/xwqsxeff/

```js
$(function(){
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;

// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}

});
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
          transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(15, 23, 84, 0.32);
}
.background:first-child {
  background-image: url(http://s8.postimg.org/lf2udl5np/4_Aihmii.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-15vh);
          transform: translateY(-15vh);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(http://s8.postimg.org/ow4wgk4px/ugqti_Lg.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(http://s8.postimg.org/grwsbtiat/x_ZMOBTj.jpg);
}

/* Set stacking context of slides */
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
          transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
      -ms-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}

#one{
background:url(http://s8.postimg.org/lf2udl5np/4_Aihmii.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#two{
background:red;
background:url(http://s8.postimg.org/ow4wgk4px/ugqti_Lg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#three{
background:url(http://s8.postimg.org/lf2udl5np/4_Aihmii.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content-subtitle{
text-transform:none;
}

#first{
color:black;
}
#second{
color:#0058FF;
}
#third{
color:rgb(236, 230, 216);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="background" id="one">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-title" id="first">Promise</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras ut massa mattis nibh semper pretium.<br />Nullam tristique urna sed tellus ornare congue. Etiam vitae erat at nibh aliquam dapibus.  </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background" id="two">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-title" id="second">Our Goal</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">Blha blah</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background" id="three">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-title" id="third">Global</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<div>
Show me too and everything after the backgrounds please
</div>
```

Side Note: If you scroll to somewhere on the page and then reload the page, the scroll stays at current location but so does the initial background.  Any idea why?  I'm assuming it has to do with the JS.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things blocking your div. First is `.background` with position fixed and `.background:before` with position absolute. (`:before` tag basically putting an element before the actual class.)

If you just want to show the div after you've done scrolling the background, follow CH's answer and manipulate it with your js.

But I assume your other div will continue to scroll like usual below the background div. In order to do that, you must

1. disable `overflow:hidden` at html, body tag
2. disable `position:fixed` at `.background`
3. Do some positioning in js for smoother transition.

Side note: I've tried your reload problem in my local and everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that the 3 sections are all being manipulated to be `position:absolute` and zpositioned in the DOM, and the simple div you list at the end has not. So it will forever live in the top left corner, at 0,0, and z-position: 0.

set your div to be something that will be able to compete:

```
#my-lonely-div{
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}
```